# Crazy series using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, series

I have to print out an arraylist of values forming a crazy series. In the crazy series, you will be given a starting number (10). Then, you need to times 2 for each number until the number is greater than 100. After the number is greater than 100, you need to divide 3 until we reach the number is less than 5. Note that
the input number must be greater than 0, and you are not allowed to use loop here.

I think the problem can be solved using recursion. I have added two methods instead of one now. The problem now though is that I can't cast type int to double with Arraylists. Is there a way to get this exercise to work using Arraylists? Thank you. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class A1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(goUp(10));
//      System.out.println(benNumber(3, 5));

    }

   /* static int benNumber(int a, int b) {
        // TODO your code goes here

    }*/

    public static ArrayList<Double> goUp(int start) {
        ArrayList theList = new ArrayList();
        theList.add(start);
        if (start <= 100) {
            start = start * 2;
            goUp(start);
        } else if (start >= 100) {
            theList.add(start);
        }
        goDown(theList);
        return theList;
    }
    public static ArrayList<Double> goDown(ArrayList<Double> theList) {
        Double start = theList.get(theList.size()-1);
        if (start >= 5) {
            start = start / 3;
            theList.add(start);
            goDown(theList);
        }
        else if (start < 5) {
            theList.add(start);
            return theList;
        }
            return theList;
    }

}
```

I tried the above code, but it only returns some of the correct values.
I was expecting an output like:

[10.0, 20.0, 40.0, 80.0, 160.0,
53.333333333333336, 17.77777777777778, 5.9259259259259265, 1.9753086419753088]

Comment: When should it stop?

Answer (score 0):

User16320675 has a valid solution for this. You can implement 2 recursive methods, one for the going up and a second for going down. Alternatively, you can implement one recursive method which carries a flag to know when the series has reversed.

```
public static void goUp(ArrayList<Double> theList)
public static void goDown(ArrayList<Double> theList)
```

or

```
public static void crazySeriesRecursive(ArrayList<Double> theList, boolean reverseDirection)
```